# What if a conference is not ranked but IEEE sponsored

Tags: publications, conference, ieee, ranking

I am trying to find conference rank of International Conference on Information and Communication Systems (ICICS) but was not successful. On core, International Conference on Information and Communication Security is listed.Could not locate it on Google scholar. Does it mean this conference is not ranked and publication from this conference will not hold any importance !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking on IEEE Xplore, it certainly appears to be a real conference, and if you search for it on plain Google Scholar (rather than Scholar metrics), you do find publications from it.  Scholar Metrics has a much tighter filter than general Scholar, and even some significant conferences don't show up in whatever arbitrary black-box algorithm Google uses to generate it.

In this case, however, this conference appears to be rather low impact, and also has a major red flag: its call for papers is about everything and nothing. Thus: legit, but not a particularly good choice of venue unless you have some particular reason to want to talk to the people who go there.

Comment: thanks for response.. my bad we did not cross check about the conference before and considered the conference with international Conference on Information and Communication Security (ICICS)! Already done with registration for my paper :( Seems like the biggest mistake of ours!